# Knapsack variation / combinatorial optimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization, combinations, combinatorics

I have a problem I need to solve that seems to be close to a Knapsack problem, but taken the other way around.
I was wondering if anyone knew the name of the exact problem - if it exists in combinatorics or combinatorial optimization - or if not, if you would have any leads or advice.

---

Basically, my problem is :
I have a **finite set of products**. All those products have a **value** associated.
I have a **total** associated with those products where I have **a total value and a total quantity**.

I want to find which products compose my total (both quantity and value).

---

More information :
1) My values are **floats** and are **not unique**.
2) The quantities of products are in [0, +inf]
3) I actually want to **get the list** of possible subsets

And basically, every total corresponds to a **daily** total.
The next day's products that compose the next day's total may come from both its daily products and the leftovers from the previous days.

---

Thank you for any indication or input on how to solve this problem.

Comment: compose my total what? value or quantity?

Comment: Both value and quantity.
For example if the total quantity is 15 and the total value is 56.12, I want to find which products correspond to that output.

Comment: this is not an optimization problem and it has nothing to do with knapsack. it could be regarded as a variation of subset sum problem which is NP-complete

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll look into it.

Comment: And by the way "Subset sum can also be thought of as a special case of the knapsack problem." ;)

Comment: it cannot because knapsack problem is an optimization problem. there is nothing to optimize in subset sum. I have seen this proposition somewhere too but I don't agree with that

Comment: there could be many subsets of a given set that will sum up to a given sum S. subset problem will simply return true if it finds just one of them, while knapsack problem returns the subset maximizing the value

Comment: Are the values / quantities integers? What is their range? What is the range for total?

Comment: Hey! I commented with more information @Primusa. I had only described what I considered being the basis of my problem :)

Comment: If they're floats you will have to test all subsets